# How to access a groovy variable in shell script in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to create a jenkins pipeline having following piece of code to get an input from user and printing that input in a shell script:

```
script{
        def user_input= input id: 'user_input', message: 'Choose a service which you want to deploy', ok: 'Confirm', parameters: [string(defaultValue: 'default', description: 'Entered value must be within range', name: 'selection', trim: true)]
        echo user_input //works fine
    
    sh '''
        #!/bin/bash
        set +x
        echo Step 2
        echo "${user_input}" //Printing blank space
        '''
     }
```

Also it works fine if i use shell like this :

```
sh "echo $user_input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for groovy variable in shell script: `sh "echo $user_input"`
And I think the other problem might be that you use `sh` outside script, where you declared `user_input` variable.